# Searching through text via batch where current path is UNC

Tags: batch-file

)

I'm making a simple batch file to search through a list of computer names and then copy over a config file to a certain folder. Config file part is fine, it's getting the script to see the text file in the UNC (where I need to run batch from) I'm having problems with. I use "%~dp0" to launch files across network on a daily basis, however in the line below it doesn't work when in the brackets. I'm hoping to get this working to add versatility and not have to worry about making paths with no spaces in.

**

> for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ("%~dp0"hostname.txt) do

** ( blah blah

**The system cannot find the file \DISKSTATION\Shared folder\Test\"hostname.txt.**
(error I'm getting)

I have had a look around and tried different places with the quotes and used single quotes instead of double but I'm not getting it. Probably because I don't know a great deal about this. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You placed the double-quotes in your `for` command the wrong way, and you need to set option `usebackq` to avoid problems with spaces in the path -- do it like:

   ```
   for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in ("%~dp0hostname.txt") do
   ```
2. Your error message shows only one leading `\`, but I guess there should be two. If the problem persists after having fixed item 1., you might add it manually like `"\%~dp0hostname.txt"` (although it's a terrible solution in my opinion...), or you could take a look at `pushd /?`, which -- when command extensions are enabled -- resolves UNC paths.

Comment: The filepath contains spaces so `usebackq` is needed to resolve that part.  Adding the extra \ should work if it does actually remove one from \\ - good idea.

Comment: I did not notice that, thanks for the hint, @foxidrive; I edited my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Test this line:  I'm uncertain what %~dp0 will return on a UNC drive.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%~dp0hostname.txt") do echo "%%i"
```